# What happened to my Ubuntu Desktop 16 today - cannot execute Python file as usual

Tags: python, ubuntu, command-line

### In brief

I can't run a simple Python file with +x permission set and shebang line.

### In Details

Let's take a simple Python code in `myApp.py` file at some `$CODE_HOME` folder

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print 122
```

When `cd $CODE_HOME` and running this file from console

```
. ./myApp.py
```

I got error as

> Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /usr/bin/print line 528.
>   Error: no such file "122333"

Though running by `python myApp.py` will get thing work.

### The question

What's wrong is that? How to fix it?

Comment: Did you mean `./myApp.py`?

Comment: Yeah it is. Updated and thank you @Iluvatar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`. myApp.py` is an instruction to Bash to source the passed file, ie execute it within the current process.

To execute a script or other file, you need to reference it by path:

`./myApp.py` (or just `python myApp.py`)

i.e. omitting the starting '.' in your call

Comment: No, your update shows you are still using the separate `.` (source) command. Why? Neither I nor Iluvatar said to do that.

Comment: Oh I see. We omit the `.` at the start. Great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as is, `.` is the `source` command, which just runs each of the commands in the argument script in the context of the calling terminal. In your case, this doesn't do anything for the first line, then tries to call `print`, as you can see in

> at /usr/bin/print line 528

Use `./myApp.py` instead.